# RDF api for PHP not returning classes with inheritance UPDATE: Trying with pOWL

Tags: php, rdf, sparql

I am using [RAP (RDF API for PHP)](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/rdfapi/) and want to be able to use the SPARQL engine to query my RDF. In this case, I am using the [W3C wine ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/wine.rdf)‎. Here is my code:

```
$base="wine.rdf";

$model = ModelFactory::getDefaultModel();
$model->load(RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR . 'wine.rdf');
$querystring = "SELECT ?wine  WHERE { ?wine rdfs:subClassOf <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#Wine> } ";
$result = $model->sparqlQuery($querystring, 'html');
```

This is supposed to return the all subclasses of the class `Wine` and print them into an HTML table (for easy reading).  It is returning a few results, but it is not returning all the classes that have this attribute by inheritance and I am getting no errors.  How can I get *all* of the subclasses of `Wine`?

UPDATE:

Had no luck using the RAP library, have moved onto using [pOWL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powl/). Another `PHP` Library with more support for `OWL` manipulation. However, it is not very well documented and having some trouble. Tried to list the SubClasses like this:

```
$base="wine.owl";
$Model = ModelFactory::getDefaultModel();
$Model->load(RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR . 'wine.owl');
$subClass = $Model->writeAsHtmlTable();
$subClass =$Model->listSubClasses;
```

But no good. Does Anybody Know of any good tutorials for `pOWL`? 
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Inferring transitive subclass relationships will require a reasoner.  An RDFS reasoner would be able to produce the simple subclass relationships, but an OWL reasoner would be needed to produce subclass relationships that depend on more complicated structures. I do see on the page you linked that one of the features is “inference engine supporting RDF-Schema reasoning and some OWL entailments,” so you may well be able to get what you need.  I haven't used this library though, so I don't know at the moment how to access that inference engine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edit Joshua, I will look into this further and update the question with any progress.

Comment: The documentation page, [Using RAP's Ontology-Centric OntModel API](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/rdfapi/tutorial/usingtheOntModelAPI.htm), says, “OntModel just provides a more convenient API for working with ontology models, but doesn't do any inference by itself. If you also need inference you have to combine OntModel with an underlying InfModelF or InfModelB. If you don't need inference you can combine OntModel with an underlying MemModel or DbModel.”  It sounds like you probably want to load an ontology/inference model and run your query against it.

Comment: Isn't [`listSubClasses()`](http://powl.sourceforge.net/api/class.RDFSClass.html) a method on classes, not models? What is `$Model->listSubClasses` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case is easily solved by SPARQL [Property Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#propertypaths).

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT ?wine  WHERE {
    ?wine (rdfs:subClassOf)+ <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#Wine>
}
```

Unfortunately, your implementation doesn't support those.

Might I suggest a real triplestore instead of file-storage? [Virtuoso/7](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/develop/7), for example, handles this quite nicely.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am now running through fuseki, with the built in reasoner, seems to be working ok.